# Cannot view data in the form using Angular 2/4

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I get data from my MongoDB backend and the data is displayed in the browser console. I managed to derive the data from the backend using the. But does not show in the Angular form. I don't know which format I should use. I tried so many formats but didn't work.

I need to display the `itemName` and `itemType` in the form. Please help me.

This is the Component.ts file:

```js
import { NgModule,Component,Pipe,OnInit,OnChanges,SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import { ItemAllocationService } from '../../../services/item-allocation.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-allocation',
  templateUrl: './allocation.component.html'
})
export class AllocationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public itemallocationservice:ItemAllocationService) { }
  itemId:Number;
  itemName:String;
  userId:Number;
  userName:String;
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  saveallocationdata(){   

    const allocateitem = {
      itemId:this.itemId,
      itemName:this.itemName,
      userId:this.userId,
      userName:this.userName
    };


     this.itemallocationservice.itemallocationdata(allocateitem).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    }); 

    }
  public x;
    getItem(){
      let x =this.itemallocationservice.getItemData(this.itemId).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);

      })
    }


}
```

The HTML file:

```html
<form name="reportitem" (ngSubmit)="saveallocationdata()">

<ba-card>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Item ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" (keyup)="getItem()" [(ngModel)]="itemId" name="itemId">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label f>Item Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="itemName" name="itemName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter the User Details to Allocate the Above Item</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>User ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userId" name="userId">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>User Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userName" name="userName">
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Allocate</button>
</ba-card>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each form item corresponds to the variables you have assigned. For example, your UserID form has an ngModel of userId. Therefore, in your subscribe method (where you have the console.log(data)), you need to assign the userId to this.userId. For example:

```
getItem(){
    this.itemallocationservice.getItemData().subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.itemId = data.itemId;
        this.itemName = data.itemName;
      });
```

Comment: Because it depends on the data object that is returned. What does "data "return?

Comment: it is the data sent from the service